# Flutter app freezes when use ListWheelScrollView with animating widgets

Tags: flutter

If there exist animated widgets such as CircularProgressIndicator, Using ListWheelScrollView widget makes app freeze (Debug/Release apk, Emulator...).

I've tested very simple code to verify it.
It works well for a while, but rendering frame drops to 0.1 after a few minutes.

```
class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(child: Listview()),
          CircularProgressIndicator()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class Listview extends StatelessWidget {
  const Listview({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListWheelScrollView(
      physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
      children: List.generate(50, (index){
        return Container(
          width: 250,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey,
            border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.blue)
          ),
          child: Text("$index")
        );
      }),
      itemExtent: 50,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be issue with device config,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution and want to share it.

I'm using fvm to manage flutter versions.
The problem occurs when I build the app by using "build button" in android studio.

However when I build the app in command console by using
"fvm flutter build apk" or "fvm flutter run",
no stuttering or freezing happened.

Still I don't know the root cause why other functions are normal and only this is a problem.

Comment: This might mean the flutter version used by fvm and android studio is different. What are those flutter versions?

Comment: @ValentinVignal I am using 3.0.5 stable on Android studio and same on fvm by "fvm use 3.0.5". My fvm has 2.10.3 and 3.0.5. Dart packages I added to my project would show error message if the flutter version was wrong when I build the project. Thank you for your opinion, and I think I should check versions again.